# Find multiple objects based on array of values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given a model `User` with the field `username` is there a way to select all users with a username in an array? I could use a for loop like so to iterate through all the usernames:

```
var usernamesToFind = ["username", "anotherUsername", "etc"];
for (i = 0; i < usernameToFind.length; i++) {
    User.find({ "username": usernamesToFind[i] }, function(err, foundUser) {
        //notify user they got tagged
    });
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the result of above loop with one query, where instead of getting username by username, I do one query and get a list of users whose username matched any of the given usernames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to query, which:

> [...] selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

```
User.find({ username: { $in: usernamesToFind } }, function(err, foundUser) {
  //...
});
```